# Table cell not resizing height appropriately on Swift

Tags: swift

I'm building an app which has a series of table cells inside a table. The cells themselves are the correct width, but their height just won't adjust. This is despite it 'looking' right on the interface builder in my .xib file.

Here's how it should look (and how look it looks in my xib file) - notice the height:

[image]

And this is how it keeps turning out in my simulator:

[image]

What I want to do is increase the height of the cells in my simulator so there's a similar level of spacing as in my xib file - but how do I do this?

I have set the height of the stack view to be 110, I've changed the row height of the cell itself to be bigger, and I've tried making the row height of the table view cell on my main storyboard bigger too - all to no success.

Can anyone tell me how to increase the height of my stack view in my simulator? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without seeng the storyboard settings for the xib it's hard to be definite, but you should look at the settings for the constraints from the top/bottom of the image / labels to the top/bottom of the cell and ensure they give you the expected spacing.

Comment: What specifically would you like to see? The spacing looks right for me - it's set to 30 on the top, which pushes it down but off the screen, not making the cell bigger.

Comment: the layout of, and the constraints between, the components in the xib. You'll need edge-to-edge continous constraints to get the cell to size correctly.